# ASP.NET MVC Error: A cyclic reference was detected while serializing an object

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Please how do I resolve this error

**A cyclic reference was detected while serializing an object**
in

```
    public JsonResult SelectStates(int id)
{
    IEnumerable<BPP.CCSP.Admin.Web.BPPCCSPAdminStatesService.STATES> states = _statesService.GetStates().Where(stat => stat.COUNTRY_ID == id);
    return Json(states);
}
```

STATES definition:

```
public int STATE_ID { get; set; } 
public Nullable<int> COUNTRY_ID { internal get; set; } 
public string STATE_NAME { get; set; }
```

Comment: how does the `STATES` class definition looks like ?

Comment: 'public int STATE_ID { get; set; }
public Nullable<int> COUNTRY_ID { internal get; set; }
public string STATE_NAME { get; set; }'

Comment: I think you need to decorate your properties with DataContract and DataMember attributes...

Answer (score 0):

It is resolved. I used this code

```
        public JsonResult GetStates(string id)
    {
        List<SelectListItem> states = new List<SelectListItem>();
        var stateList = this.Getstate(Convert.ToInt32(id));
        var stateData = stateList.Select(m => new SelectListItem()
        {
            Text = m.STATE_NAME,
            Value = m.STATE_ID.ToString(),
        });
        return Json(stateData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Thanks